# Efficient Counting of Related Objects in Serializer: Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, serialization

I have a model with a recursive relationship as such:

```
class Update(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    creator = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    update = models.CharField(max_length=140, null=True, blank=True)
    featured = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    response = models.ForeignKey('self', blank=True, null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name='responding_update')
```

I'm trying to serialize it such that it also returns the number of responses to a particular update.

```
class UpdateSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    replies = ReplyCountSerializer(read_only=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Update

class ReplyCountSerializer(serializers.RelatedField):

    def to_representation(self, instance):
        count = ??? Number of responses to the Update ???
        return count
```

What is the least expensive way to achieve what I'm looking for?